# If $G$ is an abelian group, is then $H=\{a\in G: a*a=a\}\leq G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I feel very silly for asking this question:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group. Show that $H=\{a\in G:a*a=a\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I did not get this question right, but this is what I managed to observe:

> Notice that$$a*a=a,$$$$a^{-1}*a*a=a^{-1}*a,$$$$e*a=e,$$$$a=e,$$where $a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $a$, and $e$ is the identity element. Therefore, it must be the case that $H=\{e\}$, which is a subgroup of $G$.

The professor marked that conclusion wrong, however, and corrected it by commenting that this only showed that $e\in H$.

I am a little confused: look at how $H$ is defined. I believe this is just not an intuitive exercise; I never used the fact that $H$ is abelian, so I clearly must be missing something.

Comment: To me, it seems $H=\{e_G\}$. The cancellation law tells me that.

Comment: Hence, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and not a subset as you'd write at the end of your proof.

Comment: @JosuéMolina There are no non-trivial idempotents in a group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your professor is wrong. You have showed that if $a$ is in $H$, then $a=e$. What you haven't (explicitly) showed is that $e$ *is* in $H$, but that is easy.

One way to make the question more interesting, and to make the assumption that $G$ is abelian relevant, would be to instead define $H$ as $\{ a \in G:a*a=e\}$.

Comment: Yes. The reformulation you mention is what I was wondering too.

Comment: I bet that's what the problem was supposed to be, and either professor or student typoed it into $aa=a$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $*$ is the group operation. You might want to say "let $a$ be in $H$" to begin, but requiring that is pretty pedantic. Also you're conclusion should say "*subgroup*" rather than "*subset*", but it is clear what you meant. You're argument is correct, $H=\{e\}$. I have no idea why the professor objected. [Here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Identity_Only_Idempotent_Element_in_Group) and [here](http://www.csus.edu/indiv/e/elcek/M110A/hw3_2.pdf) are proofs as citations.

Comment: Thank you for your input. In the test, I wrote that $H$ is a *subgroup* of $G$; I typo'd the last sentence here. Also, the professor wrote *"$e\in H$ but $H\neq\{e\}$!"* I believe that he must have thought that he asked us something else, as Gerry mentioned above.